# HikariPool-1 Exception during pool initialization

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

Hello guys， I am running into this error on my first trial on springboot, and the exception message makes no sense to me, the error message is as follows:

```
2022-10-03 22:27:15.801 ERROR 22836 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ��������: ���ݿ� "db_name" ������
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2675) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readStartupMessages(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2787) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.<init>(QueryExecutorImpl.java:173) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:290) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:402) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]

And my application.properties is like this:
server.port=5432
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_name
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgresSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the same port, because PostgreSQL is using port 5432, server.port is to install the port for spring to run, you can change server.port to another port eg: 80, 8080,...
you should add this line to your configuration to load the PostgreSQL driver

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

The last line should be changed to the following:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Answer (score 0):

try this properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation= true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/<database name>
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=<db password>
```